# How would food not spoiling affect society?

Tags: internal-consistency, alternate-reality

So in my setting, certain kinds of food do not spoil. To be precise: microbial spoiling is not a thing. Food still spoils due to chemical reactions(eg rancidity in oils and fats). So in what ways would this affect society?

Some specifics: Plant products never* spoil. (edit) *other than through chemical reactions. This covers kinds of spoilage other than that(/edit)However, meat ones do, until they are cooked. All uncooked meat is subject to spoilage.

Some obvious ones certainly are there: famine is less common, sieges are more ineffective as strongholds can store more food and it doesn't spoil. But would there be any drastic changes to society?

Comment: Please note that "How would X affect society?"-type of questions are invariably too broad and likely to be closed. Narrow it down considerably.

Comment: Yeah, what kind of society, what age/technology level, population density system of rule, ...

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica He's asking for the broad strokes, as he's asking for *drastic*changes. Isn't that narrow enough?

Comment: "Plant products never spoil" and "food still spoils due to chemical reactions (e.g. rancidity in oils and fats)" are contradictions. Plenty of plants have a high fat content (oats in particular are known to go rancid easily, and don't forget avocados), and most of our (cooking) oil *comes* from plants (olive, peanut, flaxseed, linseed, "vegetable"... I could keep going...). In fact, I think meats would be *more* affected by the lack of microbes (and, I presume, insects) than vegetables.

Comment: If plant products never spoil, then our lawns and parks would either be hopelessly overgrown (and useless), or we would face an endless trash-like storage crisis of where to put all the brush and lawn trimmings and fallen fruit and flower petals and pinecones and leaves and weeds that don't decay. You can only burn so much before your spouse gets annoyed.

Comment: @Matthew By that line, I meant all spoilage not covered by chemical reactions. Let me edit to be more clear. The spoilage on plant products caused by chemical reactions has been taken into account earlier

Comment: No microbial spoilage? As in no decomposition? The Earth would die in a few decades because nutrients are pulled out of the soil and never returned. Once those nutrients run dry, the plants all die from lack of chemicals - then the animals all die - then the humans all die....

Answer (score 0):

This has unintended consequences you're probably not thinking about:

There WAS a time when there were no bacteria and fungi that ate plants and trees. Basically the entire floor was made up of fallen trees and all of it is coal now.

Look at this link for example:
[https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/phenomena/2016/01/07/the-fantastically-strange-origin-of-most-coal-on-earth/#:~:text=This%20is%20a%20story%20about,shapes%20your%20life%20and%20mine](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/phenomena/2016/01/07/the-fantastically-strange-origin-of-most-coal-on-earth/#:%7E:text=This%20is%20a%20story%20about,shapes%20your%20life%20and%20mine).

> So imagine, then, these stands of towering, fernlike plants mostly
> growing in swamps. The air is warm and moist, and the land (Europe,
> the Americas, and Africa were at the time one continuous mass) is
> covered by millions—no, billions—of trees that are sucking carbon from
> the air, growing, aging, dying, falling, and releasing oxygen. This is
> a world littered with dead trees piling on top of each other.
>
> But when those trees died, the bacteria, fungi, and other microbes
> that today would have chewed the dead wood into smaller and smaller
> bits were missing, or as Ward and Kirschvink put it, they “were not
> yet present.”

For society:
The changes wouldn't probably be that big, basically population would grow until all storage was used up, then a big famine and starvation, then a new cycle (which is not that different from how things are anyway).

Comment: Since the world was created not very long ago by Gods, and humanity arrived there at the same time, there hasn't been nearly enough time for any sort of carbonification

Answer (score 0):

So there is no microbial decay of plants, and I won't assume same goes for animals as well. That would mean all the leaves and branches that fall, do not give the nutrients back to the soil. This would sooner or later mean that the soil would start to go barren, since plants will suck out nutrients but the only nutrients returning back is the ones that have been processed by animals via eating and excretion, which is a very small proportion here on earth. I assume in order to maintain balance, nature would produce various creatures that survive on those dry leaves and branches allowing its breakdown and eventual return to the soil as nutrient for plants. You have to understand, nature is all about balance, and the recycling of everything. Nature always finds a way. Another possibility is, since chemical reactions still work, there must be some chemical compounds in the air or soil that breaks down the dead leaves and branches rapidly enough so that microbial activity is unnecessary. Or perhaps the plants themselves contain some chemicals that facilitate breakdown of plant matter after cell death. And if there is no breakdown at all, then desertification is the only choice.

Comment: Yupp, there are forces in play (like certain magical ones, a whole new ecosystem for insects, etc.) Also, not all lants are immune to microbial decay, just food crops. This world was essentially designed to be a 'perfect"(ish) world, which is why strange 'no microbial decay on crops and most plants'